# Nagios bash script returns no output when executed through check_nrpe

Tags: nagios, nrpe, ipmitool

My nagios bash script works fine from the client's command line.
When I execute the same script through check_nrpe from the nagios server it returns the following message "CHECK_NRPE: No output returned from daemon."

Seems like a command in the bash script is not being executed.

```
arrVars=(`/usr/bin/ipmitool sensor | grep "<System sensor>"`)

#echo "Hello World!!"
myOPString=""
<Process array and determine string to echo along with exit code>

echo $myOPString
if [[ $flag == "False" ]]; then
        exit 1
else
        exit 0
fi
```

"Hello World" shows up on the nagios monitoring screen if I uncomment the echo statement.
I am new to linux but seems like the nagios user isn't able to execute ipmitool

Comment: Sorry,   but without the outcommented part, there is no help. your error seems to be within the not shown part of your code. Meaning, that your "$myOPString" is not getting any returnvalues for whatever command you use to get a value into it. Therefore : Please full code.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrVars=(`/usr/bin/ipmitool sensor | grep "<System sensor>"`)
```

Check the output of the above, You can echo it and check for the values. If it still does not work use another script to be called by this to get the output and assign it to a variable

```
exit 1
```

This refers to the Severity , So you would have to define different conditions where the severity changes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I echo the variable I see the message "(No output returned from plugin) " in my nagios UI. When I try running it from another script, the calling script doesn't receive any output.

Comment: Seems like nagios user doesn't have privileges to run ipmitool commands.

Comment: Ya, As i suggested earlier, If you think that the nagios user does not have the privileges to run the ipmitool, What you can do is have root execute the script with the ipmitool command and save it in a file, then have this script read the file.

Comment: Okay I get it. But I am looking for a cleaner solution. Is there a way to give the nagios user access to execute ipmitool command?

Comment: can you try to manually execute the command using the nagios user and see if that is actually the case, the we can think of a workaround, For me this has not been an issue as we too use this procedure for monitoring.

Comment: This is what happens when I run ipmitool from the command line as nagios user. Cmd :sudo -u nagios ipmitool sensor. OP: Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Device ID command failed
Unable to open SDR for reading

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the sudoers
nagios  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ipmitool

Then use "sudo /usr/bin/ipmitool" in your script